# App data usage analytics in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, analytics

I have a Rails 3 app which communicates with an iOS app via JSON web services. I want to create analytics for the data usage via the iPad client and store in the database for Rails application. 
e.g. :- Number of user hits to RSS feeds, Number of user views on the videos.

Is there any Rubygem, that can help me accomplish this? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look to https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-ruby and https://segment.com/docs/libraries/ruby/